# API Platform - How to create a custom collection operation (GET)?

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I'm starting with API Platform and I have to refactor an old API that did not use API Platform. I'm using Symfony 5 and Doctrine, I exposed entities with annotation @Api Platform and I see CRUD operations on the API doc. But I have to customize several operations and I have some difficulties.

First of all I would like to get a collection of items by a specific attribute.

The entity :

```php
/**
 * Parcsportif
 * @ApiResource(
 * collectionOperations={"get"},
 * itemOperations={"get"})
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="parcSportif", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="index_numSite", columns={"numSite"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Parcsportif
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="numParc", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $numparc;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="numSite", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $numsite = '0';

    // others attributes and getters and setters
```

The routes generated by Api platform are :

- /api/parcsportifs : GET collection
- /api/parcsportifs/{numparc} : GET item

But I would like to modify them like this :

1. /api/listeEquipements/{numsite} : GET collection by the 'numsite' attribute
2. /api/informationEquipement/{numparc} : GET item

So I changed the entity like this :

```
**
 * Parcsportif
 * @ApiResource(
 *      collectionOperations={
 *     "get"={
 *                  "method"="GET",
 *                  "path"="/listeEquipementsClient/{numsite}",
 *                  "openapi_context" = {
 *                      "parameters" = {
 *                          {
 *                              "name" = "numsite",
 *                              "in" = "path",
 *                              "description" = "numéro site",
 *                              "required" = true,
 *                              "schema"={
 *                                  "type" : "integer"
 *                              },
 *                              "style"="simple"
 *                          }
 *                      }
 *            },
 *              "controller" = ListeEquipementsController::class
 *       }
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={"get"={"path"="/informationEquipement/{numparc}"}}
 * )
```

The controller above is :

```
class ListeEquipementsController
{
    private $parcSportifRepository;

    public function __construct(ParcSportifRepository $parcSportifRepository)
    {
        $this->parcSportifRepository = $parcSportifRepository;
    }

    public function __invoke($numsite): iterable
    {
        return $this->parcSportifRepository->getListeEquipementsParNumSite($numsite);
    }
}
```

And the repository for the entity :

```
class ParcSportifRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Parcsportif::class);
        $this->em = $this->getEntityManager();
    }

    public function getListeEquipementsParNumSite($numSite): iterable
    {
        return $this->findBy([
            "numsite" => $numSite,
        ]);
    }
}
```

So the route 2) the operation "GET item" works fine, but I have the following error when I call the route 1) on Postman :

> "Unable to generate an IRI for "App\Entity\Parcsportif"."

I don't understand it.

How can I find what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When specifying `/listeEquipementsClient/{numsite}` as a path, you are telling API Platform that `numsite` is the [identifier](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/identifiers/) of your resource. Not only is `numsite` not the resource identifier (this is `numparc`, resulting in the error that you experience), collection GET operations are not supposed to expect *url path slugs* as filter parameters, but instead expect query parameters:

`/parcsportifs?numsite=123`

This should filter the `Parcsportif` collection for resources having a `numsite` value of `123`, and can be achieved by providing a `@ApiFilter` annotation to the `Parcsportif::$numsite` property:

```
/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(name="numSite", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ApiFilter(
 *      SearchFilter::class,
 *      properties={
 *          "numsite": "exact"
 *      }
 * )
 */
 private $numsite = '0';
```

If your really want to implement the endpoints described in your post (using `numsite` as a resource identifier), you will have to implement a custom resource and [data provider](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/data-providers/#custom-collection-data-provider) supporting `numsite` as an identifier for this resource.

Comment: Filter resolve my problem :) thank you :) It's easier than data provider